# Is it possible to use environment variables in java options file?

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-arguments

> Specifying Java options and system properties You can specify Java™
>   options and system properties on the command line, by using an options
>   file, or by using an environment variable.
>   ...
>   2.By creating a file that contains the options, and specifying it on the command line using -Xoptionsfile=file.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/realtime/v1r0/topic/com.ibm.rt.doc.10/user/specifying_options.html

I specified following options in options file:

```
-Xdump:what
-Xdump:java:none
-Xdump:heap:none
-Xdump:system:none
-Xdump:snap:none
-Xdump:java:events=user,range=1..2,file=$TRACEDIR/javacore.%Y%m%d.%H%M%S.%pid.%seq.txt
-Xdump:heap:events=user,range=1..2,file=$TRACEDIR/heapdump.%Y%m%d.%H%M%S.%pid.%seq.phd
```

But JVM does not evaluate environment variable $TRACEDIR.
If I do not use options file, but just add these options to command line then JVM evaluates environment variable.
Whe there is such difference?

**ANSWER:**
Command line preprocessor evaluates environment variables if you use them in command line.  Not JVM.

Comment: It doesn't say you can use environment variables *in* options files. Read it again.

Comment: I'd be sceptical if Java would parse the environment variables from the properties file, but I'd also give curly braces a go - just to be sure:
`-Xdump:java:events=user,range=1..2,file=${TRACEDIR}/javacore.%Y%m%d.%H%M%S.%pid.%seq.txt`
:-)

Comment: I've already got an answer to this question - command line preprocessor evaluates environment variables if you use them in command line.  Not JVM.

Comment: Exactly. As I said, your expectation was misplaced.